# Error message "Server Error, status code: 504" when creating an MQLight service in Bluemix via the CF CLI

Tags: service, ibm-mq, ibm-cloud, mq

I receive the error message

> "Server Error, status code: 504"

when creating an MQLight service in Bluemix via the CF CLI. What is wrong?

Comment: Please provide more details.  What is your cf syntax?   Can you provide more info from the error such as the service_instance ?

Comment: the syntax is: cf cs mqlight standard MQ-service

Comment: Creating service .....      FAILED   server error, status code:504, error code: 10001, message: The request to the service broker timed out: https://provision-broker.xx.bluemix.net/bmx.provisioning/brokers/ed45986a-1476-46a8-92ab-4897ec6879ce/v2/service_instances/0d89588a-f4c5-4932-9e18-43b8a3d64f97?accepts_incomplete=true

Comment: And thanks in advance, Valerie, for taking a look at the issue.

Comment: Hi Valerie, When I try to create the service via the Bluemix interface, the message I receive is:
 Create Service

×
The request to the service broker timed out: https://provision-broker.ng.bluemix.net/bmx/provisioning/brokers/ed45986a-1476-46a8-92ab-4897ec6879ce/v2/service_instances/0c64cbaf-80e6-4ba2-a3b6-d218cadcfa3d

So it seems the issue is with Bluemix and not only with the CLI interface.

Comment: There is currently a defect within the Bluemix provisioning broker feature that creates the service. We have a defect open and expect to have it resolved soon.

Comment: Thanks Valerie, I noticed the same issue when trying to create the service via the Bluemix interface. So I have already opened an ticket with the Bluemix support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the problem has been resolved. Today MQLight service creation works either with CLI or the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is an encountered problem already in the past days within Bluemix platform. It affects the service creation either through the CLI or UI. Please open a ticket to Bluemix Support.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks. I noticed the same issue when trying to create the service via the Bluemix interface. So I have already opened a ticket with the Bluemix support.

Answer (score 0):

@Ozz  The fix was deployed, you should now be able to create an MQ Light service in Bluemix.

Comment: Thanks Valerie, the issue is indeed solved and I could create the service with no problem.